# Segmentation fault disappears when running command from Perl

Tags: perl, segmentation-fault, child-process, exit-code

I have a simple c++ program that raises SIGSEGV:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Raising seg fault..." << std::endl;
    raise(SIGSEGV);
    return 0;
}
```

When running this program I get the following output

```
Raising seg fault...
Segmentation fault
```

But when I run my program inside a perl script using pipe, the segmentation fault disappears.
Here is my Perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my $cmd ="./test";

open (OUTPUT, "$cmd 2>&1 |") || die();
while (<OUTPUT>) {
      print;
}
close (OUTPUT);
my $exit_status = $?>>8;
print "exit status: $exit_status\n";
```

I get the following output when running the script:

```
Raising seg fault...
exit status: 0
```

How could this be possible? Where is the segmentation fault and why is the exit status 0?

Comment: What is in the low byte of `$?`

Comment: Note that the [`open`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) call actually does a fork, and runs your command in a separate process.. According to [perlipc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html): *"... readers of bogus commands return just a quick EOF"* so that might be the reason why there is no apparent indication of the SIGSEGV signal

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, uh no. The command is valid. The passage you quoted means that problems executing the command might only be revealed by `close`.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, I completely missed that! Of course you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are specifically ignoring the parts of `$?` that indicate if the process was killed by a signal.

Replace

```
my $exit_status = $?>>8;
print "exit status: $exit_status\n";
```

with

```
die("Killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("Exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n") if $? >> 8;
print("Completed successfully\n");
```

Comment: And what about the "Segmentation fault" message... Why I don't see it?

Comment: because that message is produced by the shell

Comment: `open -|` uses the same optimization as system: If you pass a shell command that consists of nothing that non-special characters, whitespace, and optionally `2>&1`, the shell isn't invoked. The shell is the source of that message. Feel free to adjust `"Killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n"` to produce the same message.

Comment: $previous_comment =~ s/nothing that/nothing but/

Comment: By the way, the fact that the shell is bypassed is why you can get accurate information about how the process exited.